# Disallow Checkout Button & Create Modal on Shop Page if Minimum Not Met

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, modal-dialog

In woocommerce, I have a shop page where all items are added to the mini-cart. I need to lockout the "Checkout" button & create a modal prompting users to add more unless minimums are met - BEFORE the checkout page. Everything I've seen requires a page reload to the checkout page. Which is lame.

Was thinking of something like this but obviously need to figure out to to change or add a class to the Checkout button & create a modal vs WC error:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process' , 'no_btn_minimum_order_amount' );

function no_btn_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 15;

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'A minimum item amount of %s is required to place your order, your current order total before shipping is %s.' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
                ), 'error' 
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet my friend @LoicTheAztec would have some ideas (;

Answer (score 0):

You can use cart fragments to update a portion of your page. I used this on cart page to update a fragment via ajax.

You can try doing this: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/